# What are some common mistakes that a designer can make when designing for web, and how can they be avoided?

Tags: website-design, design-principles, interface-design

What are some common mistakes to avoid while designing? I know color, text and images play a major part in designing, but there are so many other things that we need to take care of! I don't know those other things but I know there are so many...

Many times we get the end result with mistakes (minor-major-visible-hidden)...

**So my question is :**

- What are some of the common mistakes that we make? (you are also included honey) (it's not like nobody makes mistakes, everyone does)
- How can I/we avoid these mistakes?

Answer (score 24):

Yes, this question is incredibly broad. Maybe it's OK as a wiki article.

For starters, you need to define 'we'. There are many, many people and roles involved with designing web sites and they all tend to have different common mistakes.

Here are some issues I've seen that seem to pop-up over and over again:

- Failing to properly define the business' objectives for the website.
- Failing to properly define the key performance indicators, and subsequently failing to implement systems to measure the success of the site based on them.
- Designing for the wants of the client, rather than the needs of the client's customers.
- Not involving the necessary people, or at least considering the task from the aspect of all the needed roles.

  > Technical aspects of product management, business analysis, marketing, copywriting, database administration, back end development, graphic design, user interface design, user experience design, usability, metrics, SEO, and more, should **all** be considered.
- Failing to plan or at least sketch the design.
- Forgetting about adaptive and responsive web design principles.
- Forgetting to design for devices with screens of varying sizes and resolutions.
- Failing to consider all of the factors that affect page loading speeds during the planning stage, and not testing the speed  throughout its development.

  > Common mistakes include loading highly detailed graphics through less than optimal conditions (eg, as a background image), and in general, simply downloading too many large assets without optimising the loading conditions.
- Using wireframes as documentation, instead of the sketches they are intended to be used as.
- Not using Agile methods during development.
- Over-designing, a very common side effect of not using Agile methods.
- Choosing technologies instead of solutions.

  > For example, choosing an enterprise product for all of the reasons that make it good; even ones that don't apply to you; rather than questioning whether it's able to solve the specific issues you want it for, well.
- Forgetting about copywriting/content. This needs to come early in the process--not later.
- Designing a PhotoShop file rather than an actual web page.

  > When focused only on Photoshop, one doesn't consider factors like font variances, other devices, screen sizes, content reflowing, interaction design, and many others.
- Designing a flash file, or outlandish ideas that can only be achieved with a flash file, instead of an SEO friendly web site full of readable content.
- Building the functioning website design with focus on one particular browser instead of continuously testing in as many browsers as you can.
- Failing to apply accessibility principles while planning, designing and implementing the website.
- Waiting too long to involve users, often then finding something needs to be changed that you could have known sooner.

Comment: If we rated *questions* by the quality of the *answers* they produce, this one would be at the top of the list. Fantastic answer.

Comment: I accept i do many of this :( wish i can up vote this twice...

Comment: Lots of good points, but I think the choice of agile/scrum is a subjective decision that may not fit all projects or organizations. I personally prefer agile methods whenever possible, but, particularly in graphic design, it's not always suitable.

Comment: what does "Designing a photoshop file instead of a website" mean? too many effects? can you expand on that bullet a little?

Comment: Alan...thanks! Lese...for *most* web projects, agile is the way to go. But I agree, there are exceptions, and for other mediums, waterfall can still make a lot of sense.

Comment: @lauren I mainly mean spending all the time visually designing the site in Photoshop, rather than in HTML, CSS and JS. When focused only on Photoshop, once doesn't consider things like font variances, other devices, screen sizes, content reflowing, etc.

Comment: @user go for it!

Comment: @user good edits! but a bit hard to follow as you re-arranged them all. But I think you have everything in there. I only had one minor quibble (that was emphasizing the hazards of PhotoShop--which I feel is a much different hazard, albeit somewhat related--than wireframing tools)

Answer (score 3):

I think a very common mistake in web design is evident on the mobile web.

If you browse the web on a small mobile device, such as iPhone or BlackBerry, you will notice that sometimes the buttons are too small.

Now this isn't always the button itself, but one mistake that is made is that there is often not enough room around the button.

Lets assume we are doing a survey and there is a back button and a next button next to each other, they need breathing space so the user can press the button and not tap on the wrong one by accident.

This is a common thing and a major consideration in email design for the mobile user.

Comment: I find this to be true on the SE mobile sites.  I constantly tap the "ask question" link when I'm intending to get the user-account drop-down.

Answer (score 2):

I think DA01's answer is already an excellent list of things to consider. I'm adding my answer both because it's important and to bump the question as I'd really like to see more answers to this.

Another very important consideration in designing a website is speed. Being aware of all the factors that affect **page load speeds** before you begin designing should help to ensure you don't spend a lot of time creating graphics and architecture that you later have to completely change because the website takes 30 seconds (extreme example) to load.