# Evaluate a Good Web Design

Tags: website-design

How to evaluate a good web design. Is there any pre-defined ways to **measure** someones Design.
I understand the Analytics can be used to evaluate, still looking for any other open solutions.
For instance a new design can have Flat Design or Material design but is this what say that the Design is good.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Every design principle ever is applicable. As such, I'm voting to close this question

Comment: Loosely Related / Possibly Useful: [What are some common mistakes that a designer can make when designing for web, and how can they be avoided?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5037/what-are-some-common-mistakes-that-a-designer-can-make-when-designing-for-web-a)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty detailed list of questions every website owner should asked themselves. If the answer to every question  below is yes, give yourself a big ole pat on the back.  Most websites have flaws for a number of different reasons, mostly related to the limitation of resources.

### Design

- Is the site’s design aesthetically appealing?
- Are the colors used harmonious and logically related?
- Are the color choices visually accessible? (For example high enough in contrast to assist the colorblind and visually impaired in reading the site appropriately)
- Is the design audience appropriate?- The standard text size should be readable for visitors who don’t know how to adjust their browsers.
- Are the fonts easy to read on various screen resolutions?
- It's Responsive or not ?
- Does my website’s style align with my brand in terms of colors, feel, graphics, etc?
- Is the style consistent throughout the website?
  Will the style suit my target audience? (i.e., cartoons on a toy company website, elegant layout on a legal website)
- What feel does the website give—Orderly or messy? Sparse or crowded? Playful or formal?—and how does that align with my goals?
- Where are photos or decorative touches getting in the way of my message?

Beauty may be relative, but that doesn't mean there aren't clear aesthetic principles to guide your website design. The best designs will align with their brands, create positive impressions for visitors, be clean, and complement the content they’re communicating.